# Where should I put this, in the model, a helper, or a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a view that I call `school.html.erb` and in that view I have Ruby code that calculates the average rating for that school.

**Like this:**

```
<span class="label label-info">
 <%= @school.reviews.average(:rating).round(1) unless @school.reviews.blank? %>
</span>
```

I like to move this somewhere else, should I put this in the model, a helper or in a controller. And if I do that how can I call it from the view.

I have the following models: `User`, `Review` and `School`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating the average belongs in the model:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  def average_review_rating
    return nil if reviews.blank?
    reviews.average(:rating)
  end

end
```

Rounding the average belongs in the view, because it is formatting.  Put calculation in the model, and formatting in the view (or a helper).

```
<%= @school.average_review_rating.round(1) if @school.average_review_rating %>
```

This can be shorted considerably using the [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) gem.

```
<%= @school.average_review_rating.andand.round(1) %>
```

You may wish to push the rounding into the helper, where it can be independently tested:

```
class SchoolHelper

  def format_rating(n)
    n.andand.round(1)
  end

end
```

which is used like this:

```
<%= format_rating(@school.average_review_rating) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I makes a lot of sense to put it into a model as a method.

```
class School
  def avg_rating
    reviews.average(:rating).round(1) unless reviews.blank?
  end
end
```

Why it makes sense? Well, school rating is something you'll likely have to access in plenty of other places: other views, other models, etc. By putting it into a method, you may it look like just a property of `School`. `school.avg_rating` is pretty much saying for itself: "School, what's your rating?"

Why view won't do? You may want to access it in other views. There are helpers for that, right? But why helpers won't do? You may also want to access it from other models. Helpers aren't meant to calculate data, they're meant to format it and do other similar stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Put in in the model (School):

```
def reviews_average
  reviews.average(:rating).round(1) unless reviews.blank?
end
```

View:

```
<%= @school.reviews_average %>
```

**Reason:** Do not put DB intensive procedures into the view because the rendering speed depends on it.

Comment: Are you sure there's a performance benefit to moving the query into the model?  It seems to me that it will take the same amount of time either way.

Comment: I thought so too.. To prove it just try to run something within view and look at the time response. Most often, the difference is imperceptible, but it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it works best in the model, because it's working with the data. This kind of follows [the "fat model, skinny controller" principle](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model).

Another rational option would be a decorator or presenter, using a library like [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper).